# Eclipse JBoss Plugin - Cannot start my Server a second time

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, noclassdeffounderror

I have a really strange problem. I can successfully start my Eclipse internal JBoss Server (7.0.2). I can access the website and everything is fine. But after restarting or shutting down and starting again I always receive the following error out of nowhere:

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/path/Coding/JBoss
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Users.robin.Coding.JBoss
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I googled and looked in the JBoss forums. Some ppl had a problem with using the JRE Version instead of the JDK. I checked I am using the JDK 1.6..

Here some other informations:

- Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1)
- JBoss (jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final) also tested with the newer version 7.1
- JBoss Tools (3.3.x)
- Java version "1.6.0_29"
- Mac Os X 10.7.3 (Lion)

After deleting the internal Server in Eclipse and recreating I can again start it successfully the first time. The path to the external JBoss directory is correct.

Did anyone have the same problem or any idea what it could be?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the 'Home Directory' variable of your JBoss 7.0 Runtime?

Comment: Hey! Your comment brought me to the solution. The 'Home Directory' was set correctly. But I had in my path a space '/Users/robin/Coding/JBoss Servers/...' so somehow it could run it without a problem the first time but the second time it crashes because of the space. Very strange. But thanks for your comment! Gonna post it as solution for other ppl who are also having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's very strange but somehow after executing the Server a second time it's crashing because of the space in the path:

*/Users/robin/Coding/JBoss Servers/..'*

After removing the space I could also run the Server several times without crashing. Thanks to *Perception*, his comment was leading me to the solution.